# uiimage to XBM format in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

I'm having a requirement where I need to convert an image to XBM format in iPhone. Please let me know if there are any libraries available in objective C?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can't do it and no third party libraries available yet.